# setparent fail for database sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I have an SQLServer 2012 and I'm trying to restore a BAK file , the error I get is

```
setparent failed for database 'dbname'
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem reason , SMO version not the same in the project and the BAK